# SOAPUI: Send 100 XML messages to SOAP Web Server

Tags: soapui, soap-client

I want to send 1 message about 100 times within the same second (or with some milliseconds delay) to a remote web server using SOAP UI. Unfortunately, I don't know how to configure the Load Test feature in SOAP UI properly to achieve this:

[image]

Which values do I have to apply to:

- Threads
- Strategy
- Test Delay
- Limit

Can anyone help me please?

Thanks

Comment: Does this help: [Simulating different types of Load](https://www.soapui.org/docs/load-testing/simulating-different-types-of-load/)?

Comment: Also have a read through: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)